# Show all environment variables in Vxworks

Tags: vxworks

Is there a command in the vxworks shell that lists all the environment variables and their current values? This is very much possible in unices and could be of help in some situations.

Comment: I hope the answer below has helped - if so please share the love by upvote/accept as appropriate. If not, please let us know why not so the answer can be improved. You might also want to take a look at your question history, as you appear to have a few questions with good, but unaccepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific command to print the global environment, however you can get there by using `envShow()`. `envShow()` shows all the environment variables for an identified task. eg:

```
->envShow tNet0
(global environment)
value = 21 = 0x15 = __local_cie + 0x1
```

This example prints the environment for tNet0, which is using the global environment. There are no environment variables displayed, as I don't have any set.

You can show the environment of the calling task as well:

```
->envShow 0
(private environment)
value = 22 = 0x16 = __local_cie + 0x2
```

This shows that the calling task - in this case tShell - uses a private environment. Again, there are no variables set, otherwise they would be displayed.

And lets set an environment variable just to prove it works:

```
->putenv("bar=foo")
value = 0 = 0x0
->envShow 0
(private environment)
0: bar=foo
```

If you are willing to do a source build, you could modify envLib.c to add a command to directly dump the global environment, which would be fairly trivial. Alternatively, just use envShow as described. You may need a little trial and error to find a task using the global environment.

Comment: I was looking for a command that will print the list of all globally applicable environment variables,  akin to the output of the 'set'  command on Unix shells when the command is executed without any argument.

Comment: The above should do that, as long as the task you choose is one using the global environment, not a private environment, for instance in my example tNetTask uses the global environment